# Recieve global variable (Cython)

Tags: python, cython

I am using Cython in jupyter notebook.

As I know, Cython compiles def functions.

But when I want to call function with global variable it doesn't see it.

Are there any method to call function with variable?

```
one1 = 1
%%cython
cimport numpy as np
cdef nump(number1):
    return number1 + 1
nump(one1)
```

****This is sample code, to show moderators

Comment: please, post your code here or a sample containing what you try to do. It will help the answers to understand your problem.

Comment: Take a look at [ask]

Comment: @Abe Very big code, I cant show it here. It is simple question, that will understand cython devs

Comment: @pvg there are a lot questions without code. I need answer to my question without codw

Comment: It's not just about what you need, it is also what the people you are expecting to help you need as well (and more importantly) what other people with a similar question might find helpful in the future. The purpose of the site is not really to meet your immediate personal needs.

Comment: @pvg trust me, people who need it, understand it. Give me 24 hours, if nobody will understand, I will delete question. Or you will block me

Comment: I don't understand what that means. Just read the site docs and improve your question.

Comment: @pvg cython is a library that converts python code to c and compiles it. It compiles one big code. To show here my code, I should copy my 3000+ lines of code to here. Do you think anybody will understand it?

Comment: I know what Cython is, thanks. Your 3000 lines of code are not relevant to your question, this is covered in the docs - again, you should read them, for instance [MCVE]. You seem to be a lot more interested in arguing about the quality of your question than getting help. Fix your question.

Comment: @pvg I need global variable in cython, it is a question!

Comment: "It is a question" is not good enough. "Why is the sky blue" is also a question.

Comment: Sometimes you need to write a small script that illustrates the problem.  Most likely the answer to your question (if any) will illustrate it with working code.  You are more likely to get a answer if you give us a framework to start with.

Comment: One thing that needs to cleared up - is the compiled code supposed to be using this global variable, or is it calling a Python function that uses such a variable?  Even in pure Python there's a significant difference between using a global variable (i.e. one defined outside the function), and modifying such a variable (which requires the `global` marker).

Comment: @pvg is it enough?

Comment: @hpaulj thx man, can you check my edit?

Comment: ...`return np.append(number1)`? That's not how NumPy works, let alone Cython.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an `Ipython` session I can do:

```
In [2]: %load_ext Cython
In [3]: one = 1
In [4]: %%cython
   ...: def foo(num):
   ...:    return num + 1
   ...: 
In [5]: foo(one)
Out[5]: 2
```

That is I define a `cython` function, but call it from Python with the global variable.

If I define the function with `cdef` I need to invoke it with a `def` function.  `fooc` is not visible from Python.

```
In [9]: %%cython
   ...: cdef fooc(num):
   ...:    return num + 2
   ...: def foo_call(num):
   ...:    return fooc(num)
   ...: 
In [10]: foo_call(one)
Out[10]: 3
```

If I attempt to use `one` from within the `cython` file (magic cell) I get an error, the equivalent of a Python NameError

```
In [8]: %%cython
   ...: cdef fooc(num):
   ...:    return num + 2
   ...: print(fooc(one))
   ...: 

Error compiling Cython file:
...
/home/paul/.cache/ipython/cython/....: undeclared name not builtin: one
```

The `ipython` session variable `one` is not visible from within the magic cell.

---

Working from @DavidW's answer, this `import` works:

```
In [14]: %%cython
    ...: from __main__ import one
    ...: cdef fooc(num):
    ...:    return num + 2
    ...: print(fooc(one))
    ...: 
3
```

This `fooc` is not accessible from Python.

Note that the `import` uses the value of `one` at compile time.

```
In [22]: %%cython
    ...: from __main__ import one
    ...: cdef fooc(num):
    ...:    return num + 20
    ...: def fooc_call():
    ...:    print(fooc(one))
    ...: 
    ...: 
In [23]: fooc_call()
21
In [24]: one=343           # new value
In [25]: fooc_call()        # no change
21
In [26]: foo_call(one)     # uses the current value
Out[26]: 345
```

Comment: It means, there is no option?

Comment: I added @DavidW's suggestion to my answer.

Comment: What to do,  to pick you answer or his answer?

Comment: would `one` be usable in cython even if it were a python function and not a python variable?

Answer (score 6):

Your code has a few errors, but I think the one you are asking about is one the line `nump(one1)` which gives the error

> `undeclared name not builtin: one1`

This is because your `%%cython` snippets are essentially built in their own module. The `%%cython` magic in jupyter is more designed to create compiled functions that are accessible in your main code, rather than to access variables in your main code.

One solution is to add the line

```
from __main__ import *
```

at the start of your Cython block, to gain access to the "top level" scope. The answer @hpaulj has posted suggests the better approach where you define functions in Cython and use them outside the block.