# turn function in python file into cython and use it in Juypter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cython, cythonize

I am writing algorithm code in python files and using it in my Jupyter notebook that sits at the root of my code project's path. I am trying to cythonize one python function (from my python files) and use it in the Jupyter notebook, but haven't succeeded in that yet.

I have used `cythonize -i` to cythonize my particular python source file,  in place; that indeed results in `.c` and `.so` files next to the original source file. So my python function `my_func` is in a source file `foo/bar/my_func.py` relative to the Jupyter home directory, and it has been successfully cythonized now.

The source file is *not* a module, I like functional programming so I'm in no rush to create objects and modules.

I then have in my Jupyter notebook:

```
%load_ext Cython

import sys, os
import pyximport
pyximport.install(reload_support=True)
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'foo', 'bar'))
```

Last line above indeed brings the correct full path to the cython files into `sys.path`, in case that's necessary for cython, even though it was unnecessary for using the python code prior to pursuing cython. I have not changed how I import the function:

```
from foo.bar.my_func import my_func # as my_func.py contains my function `my_func`
```

But on my next cell I try to use `my_func` inside of a cython cell, and it fails to load my `my_func` cython function, whereas loading that function before going the cython way used to seamlessly work:

```
%%cython

.
.
.
def get_sameness_candidate(text):
    for term in positive_terms:
        term_distance_threshold = my_func(term, 5, 1.5)
.
.
.
```

cython is not finding the function:

> cython_magic_5fb62d79423f13c25e1c53012d355e04.pyx:8:28: undeclared name not builtin: my_func

In addition to not finding out how to make this work, I'm happy to learn how to know whether an import statement is actually loading a cython or a python version of my code, I'm not sure how to tell in the general case.

Thanks!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46223278/recieve-global-variable-cython - I'm reluctant to mark your question as a duplicate since the other question is a much worse question, but the answer is the same: the "global jupyter" scope isn't automatically accessible within Cython, but you can import individual symbols with `from __main__ import my_func`

Comment: @DavidW Thanks so much for pointing out this angle, it is seamlessly working now :-) I just made sure to import my cython function inside the `%%cython` cell, that solved the error message, but actually I have no way telling whether my cell is now using the cython version of the python version of `my_func`, to confirm I'm really loading the cython version.

Comment: Do `print(type(my_func))` - that should confirm if it's the Cython version or not

Comment: @DavidW Wow, as simple as unthinkable :) and it is..... `cython_function_or_method`, question solved. Would you like to post an orderly answer, or leave the hassle to me? I'd just like to post a fully working code example as long as this question is up here on SO.

Comment: I'm not feeling particularly motivated to write an answer, so feel free to do it yourself :)